# wrong value of version within package.json

Tags: gulp

I'm trying to setup a publish task that do the following:

pull latest changes.
do npm install.
bump new version.
generate the bundle.
I inject variable refer to the version property within the package.json file, The issue I'm encutering is, the generated bundle contains the old version value which is the value at the begining of the task, not after step 3. The expected behavior that after completion of step 3 the generated bundle should have the correct version value.
The actual behavior is, the generated bundle contains old version since the beginning of the main task(publish:test).

**So what is happening, I noticed that the main task is keeping the package.json file in memory for the whole interval of the task, it doesn't read the file again after step 3.**

I'm injecting the version variable into the generated bundle using the webpack plugin:

```
ew webpack.DefinePlugin({
        VERSION: JSON.stringify(require('../package').version),
        SERVER: JSON.stringify(require('../package').TEST_SERVER),
        ENV: JSON.stringify("TEST"),
        LANDING_PAGE: JSON.stringify(require('../package').TEST_LANDING_PAGE)
    })
```

Code:

```
gulp.task('bump', function(done) {
    return gulp.src(['./package.json'])
    // bump package.json and bowser.json version
        .pipe(bump({
            type: argv.type || 'patch'
        }))
        // save the bumped files into filesystem
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./'))
        // commit the changed files
        .pipe(git.commit('bump version'))
        // filter one file
        .pipe(filter('package.json'))
        // create tag based on the filtered file
        // push changes into repository
        .pipe(push({
            repository: 'origin',
            refspec: 'HEAD'
        }))
        .on('error', function(error) {
            gutil.log(gutil.colors.red('Error occurs while pushing changes, please try again.'));
            git.reset('HEAD~1', {args:' --hard '}, function (err) {
                if (err) {
                    gutil.log(gutil.colors.red('Please execute the following command before you processed:\n git reset --hard HEAD~1'));
                    done(err)
                } else {
                    done(error);
                }
            });
        })
        .on('end', function (done) {
            // console.log('VERSION$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$', JSON.stringify(require('./package').version));

        })

});

gulp.task('pull-changes', function(done) {
    git.pull(function (err) {
        if (err) {
            const error = 'Unable to pull latest changes, please check your username & password.'
            gutil.log(gutil.colors.red(error));
            done(err);
        } else  {
            done()
        }
    });
});


gulp.task('install-dependencies',  function(done) {
    return gulp.src(['./package.json'])
        .pipe(install({
            npm: '--no-optional', // Either a single argument as a string
        }));
});


// build test bundle.
gulp.task('build:test', gulp.series('clean', gulp.parallel('other', 'webpack:test')));

gulp.task('publish:test', gulp.series('pull-changes', 'install-dependencies', 'bump',  'build:test'));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, The reason for this is the cache feature within the require module. I deleted the cached entry after step 3 and everything works like a charm!
The rescue was this code:

```
delete require.cache[require.resolve('./package.json')]
```